# How to disable warning in React Native ?

Tags: react-native, warnings

I know warnings are important. But I don't want them on screen for the specific reason. How to disable those yellow colored warnings appearing on `screen`

Comment: Which warnings?

Comment: those warnings specifying like `invalid props type` or `netInfo` deprecated etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its advisable to note that this won't show up on a release build...but if you want to remove the warnings, you can set `console.disableYellowBox = true`

More info in the documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#warnings

Comment: thank you. I just ignored this in docs. I get this. I don't want all warning to be ignored rather specific which I got through your docs link.

Comment: @Revansiddh Hah. No problem!

Comment: This way to disable warnings is depricated. Now you need to use
_LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(disable);_

Answer (score 15):

`console.disableYellowBox` has been deprecated in favor of `LogBox.ignoreAllLogs()`

In index.js just set:

```
import { LogBox } from "react-native"

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true)
```

or

```
import { YellowBox } from "react-native"

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(["Warning: ..."])
```

Good coding!

Answer (score 3):

`console.disableYellowBox = true;` to index.js .enjoy