# React Native - How do you hide warning in Android Device Monitor?

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, console.log

I'm confused about the warning in `Android Device Monitor` that showing me an error about `View` needed some unique `key` but the `Yellow Box` doesn't appears in my screen,

[image]

The warning error makes me confused to debugging the apps,

Is there a way how to hide the warning message?

> Edited

My question ***Completely*** different about [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293636/how-to-disable-warning-in-react-native)

***Reason :***

`console.disableYellowBox = true` is just hide the warning on my screen not in `Android Device Monitor` like this:

[image]

Comment: @Revansiddh I've used it to hide the warning _**on my screen**_ not _**on Android Device Manager**_

Comment: you mean you dont want those warning on `console` ?

Comment: @Revansiddh yep, does my title is not clearly enough?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642964/set-android-studio-warning-levels hope this will help you

Answer (score 9):

add the following code in your index.js file

```
console.disableYellowBox = true
```

Answer (score 4):

// put these lines inside `index.js`

```
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: ...']);

console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

Comment: can you explain why the `react-native` part needed? seems to work with only `console.disableYellowBox = true;` too

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging  follow it